# Deploy django app to vps server using cyberpanel

Tags: django, hosting, vps, litespeed

I am trying to deploy django app to vps server using cyberpanel.I followed the steps in the doc, here is the link to the doc (https://community.cyberpanel.net/t/how-to-setup-django-application-on-cyberpanel-openlitespeed/30646), but the site gives 500 Internal Server Error
In the Error log, this error appears

2022-10-31 06:15:44.516946 [INFO] [126625] [wsgi:futuurelineworkshop.com:/]: locked pid file [/tmp/lshttpd/futuurelineworkshop.com:*.sock.pid].
2022-10-31 06:15:44.516975 [INFO] [126625] [wsgi:futuurelineworkshop.com:/] remove unix socket for detached process: /tmp/lshttpd/futuurelineworkshop.com:*.sock
2022-10-31 06:15:44.517516 [NOTICE] [126625] [LocalWorker::workerExec] VHost:futuurelineworkshop.com suExec check uid 99 gid 99 setuidmode 0.
2022-10-31 06:15:44.517541 [NOTICE] [126625] [LocalWorker::workerExec] Config[wsgi:futuurelineworkshop.com:/]: suExec uid 99 gid 99 cmd /usr/local/lsws/fcgi-bin/lswsgi -m /home/futuurelineworkshop.com/public_html/workShop2/WorkShop/wsgi.py, final uid 99 gid 99, flags: 0.
2022-10-31 06:15:44.518080 [NOTICE] [126625] [wsgi:futuurelineworkshop.com:/] add child process pid: 146100
2022-10-31 06:15:44.518154 [INFO] [126625] [wsgi:futuurelineworkshop.com:/]: unlocked pid file [/tmp/lshttpd/futuurelineworkshop.com:_.sock.pid].
2022-10-31 06:15:45.031045 [NOTICE] [126625] [127.0.0.1:44700#futuurelineworkshop.com] Premature end of response header.

I am trying to deploy django app to vps server using cyberpanel.I followed the steps in the doc, here is the link to the doc (https://community.cyberpanel.net/t/how-to-setup-django-application-on-cyberpanel-openlitespeed/30646), but the site gives 500 Internal Server Error
In the Error log, this error appears

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The post you followed has an incorrect ENV setup. Here is the good example,

```
Environment: LS_PYTHONBIN=/home/django.example.com/public_html/bin/python3

Environment: PYTHONPATH=home/django.example.com/public_html/lib/python3.8:/home/django.example.com/public_html/myegg
```

Reffer from https://egg-souffle.medium.com/how-to-setup-django-on-cyberpanel-faf48d77918c